# How to do property injection for TypeAliases using spring.net

Tags: c#, spring.net

I am facing issues in creating object using spring.net and need solutions to that.

**Setup Description**:
I have below configuration file for TypeAliases.

```
<objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net" >
    <object id="TypeAlias" type="Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.TypeAliasConfigurer, Spring.Core">
        <property name="TypeAliases">
            <dictionary>                
                <entry key="ABCHost" value-ref="XYZ"/> 
            </dictionary>
        </property>
    </object>
     <object id="XYZ" type="ABC.ABCHost, ABCHost" >
        <property name="Viewer" ref="ViewerFactory" />
     </object>
</objects>
```

Why i am doing property injection is because the ObjectPoolFactory uses a default constructor. While object creation I want this Viewer property to get created via below spring file.

```
<object id="ViewerFactory" type="XYZViewerFactory, XYZViewer" singleton ="true">
  </object>
```

**Issue**:
While running the application I get a call to default constructor of ABCHost class and viewer property gets the value as XYZViewer. After that I get a spring error -

```
ServiceProvider.get_AppContext - ServiceProvider.cs(31)
  Spring Error : 
Spring.Objects.Factory.ObjectInitializationException: 
------------------------------------
--- Message
------------------------------------
Invalid value 'ABCHost' for custom type alias - must be a System.String or System.Type.

------------------------------------
--- Stack Trace
------------------------------------
   at Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.AbstractConfigurer.ResolveRequiredType(Object value, String errorContextSource, String errorContext)
```

Could you help in finding the solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: any solution found?

Answer (score 0):

TypeAlias is defined using very simple xml configuration OUTSIDE spring/objects:

```
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="spring">
      <!-- other configuration section handler defined here -->
      <section name="typeAliases" type="Spring.Context.Support.TypeAliasesSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/> 
     </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <spring>
    <typeAliases>
       <alias name="WebServiceExporter" type="Spring.Web.Services.WebServiceExporter, Spring.Web"/>
    </typeAliases>
  </spring>

</configuration>
```

Look at [docs](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html) to see more.

TypeAlias is defined in spring/typeAliases structure.